# Highlight cell or row depending on the value/text from another cell/row or worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im working on a excel list to know which members of the team took a training. I need to highlight the member id if the id appears on the training worksheet (this is the list were i put only who credits the course).

```
**ID    Training    DEPT    NAME    MGR
12345   TRUE    IT  JOHN DOE    JANNE DOE**
```

I tried this conditional format

```
Rule: =$B:$B=Training!$A:$A
Applied to: =$B$2:$B$1190
```

(the rows i would light to highlight)

---

And this

```
=COUNTIF(Training!A:A,D2)>0
```

and the conditional format applied to the cell, or the row.

Also used the match formula with a conditional format but nothing is working.

The only option that works... is if i put Rule: `=$D2=TRUE  COLOR GREEN, BOLD`.. but when i change the "applied to" to all the row, stops working.

Im running out of ideas, but probably im just using them in the wrong way.

Hope somebody can guide me a little to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not able to recreate your issues. I was able to get it working:

"Sheet1" is the main page, with your ID, Training, DEPT, Name, etc. all across.
"Sheet2" is the "training worksheet". With `Sheet1!A2` selected, use:

`=Countif(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A2)>0`

I think you accidentally used `D2` as the `Countif` variable, when you want the ID in column A, no?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am trusting that the `D` is significant (ie NAME is in ColumnA of Training, not ID) and suggest selecting ColumnA:E of the sheet not called Training and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(Training!$A:$A,$D1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

This is near identical to your effort except (i) that choosing whole columns (for simplicity) to apply the CF formula rule to means starting in Row1 (ie `D1` rather than `D2`), (ii) perhaps the key, anchoring the column (ie `$D1`) so that the same cell affects the whole row within the *Applies to* range and (iii) leaving off `>0` since not required.